# How to modify autocomplete so that I can search for only 1 word?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, autocomplete, vue-component, vuetify.js

My template like this :

```
<v-autocomplete
        label="Components"
        :items="components"
      ></v-autocomplete>
```

My component like this :

```
  data () {
    return {
      components: [
        'Manchester United', 'Manchester City', 'Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'Tottenham Hotspurs', 'Everton', 'Arsenal', 'AC Milan', 'Inter Milan', 'Real Madrid', 'Atletico Madrid',
      ],
    }
  },
```

Demo and full code like this :

https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/yLyKaZR?editors=1010

For example I type "manchester", it will show manchester city and manchester united

But I don't want to choose both. I just want to input the word "Manchester" only

How can do it?

**Update** :

I want there to be 2 options. The user can choose from autocomplete and the user can also search by keyword

option 1: user input manchester, user selects manchester united, user click search then the search result will display data manchester united

option 2: user input manchester, user click search then the search results will display data manchester united and manchester city

Comment: You should look into the "combobox" component - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox

Comment: @Justice47 Great. That seems like a great idea. Thanks